# Batch : Echo Two parameters with space

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am working on Batch scripting and facing some problem while echo two variables. For this I created the file
test.bat

> echo %2%
>
> echo "Calling Two Paramters"
>
> echo - %1% %2%

When calling, what output comes:

```
test.bat 1235 899
899
"Calling Two Paramters"
- `12352`
```

Now Expected Output must be:

```
1235 899
```

PLease help

Comment: Do you want `1235 899` to be treated as a single parameter, or do you want it to be seen as two arguments `1235` and `899`?

Comment: Two different Arguments

Comment: Okay... so the correct last line is: `echo - %~1 %~2` (as @npocmaka already pointed out in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37112843) there is only one `%` for arguments, and the `~` modifier removes potential surrounding qouotes; obviously your question was not clear enough to him though -- like also for me -- so he interpreted the two numbers as a *single* argument)...

Comment: Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

**Your error:**

When using arguments in batch files, there is no trailing percentage character. So the first argument is *%1*, and not *%1%*.

**Bonus tip:**

I like to use *@echo off* as the first line in batch files, so the command interpreter doesn't echo all lines before parsing (and executing) them.

**Example:**

```
@echo off
echo %2
echo "Calling Two Paramters"
echo - %1 %2
```

You can ditch the *@echo off* if you don't want it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alter your test.bat like this:

```
echo "Calling Two Paramters"

echo - %~1
```

and call it like this:

> test.bat "1235 899"

Subroutine and batch file arguments are have `%` only at the beginning.

Arguments with delimiters need to be enclosed with double quotes.

`%~1` the tilda here is used for dequoting.

Comment: No. I have two different argunents as I need to pass those two to calling script in which first one is my streamname and second is version.

Comment: @R.Sha - then you can use just `echo %1 %2`

Answer (score -1):

Modify your script's last line like this:

```
echo %1 %2%
```

Comment: This would works, but because of a hack that causes the last `%` to be interpreted as the start of an empty variable. Better would be to use `echo %1 %2`, or even better `echo %~1 %~2`